# Question about Vector Calculus

Tags: vector-analysis

Mine is probably a very trivial question. I didn't get good training on vector calculus and I am not able to find the correct materials to learn to understand the following equation.

Given

$F = \int \frac{D^2}{8\pi\epsilon} dV$

where $\vec{D}$ is a vector, the book gives:

$\delta F=\int\frac{\vec{D}\cdot\delta\vec{ D}}{8\pi\epsilon}-\int\frac{D^2}{8\pi\epsilon^2}dV$

Can you explain why the 1st term is not $\int\frac{\vec{D}\cdot\delta\vec{ D}}{4\pi\epsilon}$? I would like to understand more about vector differential (is this what it call?). Can you give a suggestion on what this is called so that I can google the right keyword to learn more? Thanks a lot!

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: What book?$ $ $ $

Comment: What is $\delta F$? Some kind of variation?

Comment: This is the "Electrodynamics of Continuous Media" by Landau and Lifshitz on page 58.

Comment: I just uploaded the snapshot.

Comment: How's $D^2$ defined?

Comment: It is defined as: $D^2=\vec{D}\cdot\vec{ D}$

Comment: Also $\vec{D} = \epsilon \vec{E}$.

Comment: Seems like it should be factored by $\frac 1{4 \pi \varepsilon}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have to say you're very brave for reading Landau and Lifshitz's Volume 8 about electrodynamics of continuous media $\ddot{\smile}$.

---

Anyway, you're right, it should be $4 \pi \epsilon$ in the denominator of the first term, and in my version of the book, that's how it is stated (so perhaps, yours is an older edition with typos?). So, we have:
\begin{align}
\delta\mathcal{F} &= \int\dfrac{\mathbf{D} \cdot \delta \mathbf{D}}{4 \pi \epsilon} \, dV - \int \dfrac{D^2}{8 \pi \epsilon^2} \delta \epsilon \, dV
\end{align}

Anyway, this $\delta$ operation being done on the various quantities is called the "variation".

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps a lot!